# Remove last character from string column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I have these special characters " ||~|| " at the end of each value in column X. I need to remove these special characters.

Right now I am using this syntax, but it doesn't seem to accomplish the task for all rows.

```
set [Customer Num] = substring(ltrim(rtrim([Customer Num])),3,len([Customer Num]))
```

Comment: How may time character ~ will occur in your string?

Comment: Is the character '|' present anywhere else in the string?

Comment: `LEN([Customer Num])` is giving you the length of the entire column. But if `LTRIM(RTRIM())` have had any effect, that's probably not the length you're interested in. Can you give some example values, and also tell us what the definition is for the column (e.g. what type of `[n][var]char[(l)]` is it)?

Comment: ||~|| appears at the end of each [customer num]  and type is nvarchar

Comment: @user3518233, have you got your ans.?

Answer (score 5):

Try this options,

```
Declare @myStr varchar(50) = 'amol~'
```

--If want to remove char ~ of any position

```
Select REPLACE(@myStr,'~','')

Set @myStr = '~amol~'
Select REPLACE(@myStr,'~','')

Set @myStr = '~am~ol~'
Select REPLACE(@myStr,'~','')
```

--If want to remove character ~ at Last position & existance of char ~ is inconsistent
    Set @myStr ='amol~'

```
Select Case When RIGHT(@myStr,1) = '~'
            Then LEFT(@myStr,len(@myStr) - 1)
            Else @myStr
        End
```

If you are looking to replace ||~|| Then try this,

```
Declare @myStr varchar(50) = 'amol ||~|| '

--If want to remove string ||~| of any position
Select REPLACE(@myStr,'||~||','')
Set @myStr = '||~||amol||~||'
Select REPLACE(@myStr,'||~||','')
Set @myStr = '||~||am||~||ol||~||'
Select REPLACE(@myStr,'||~||','')

--If want to remove string ||~| at Last position & existance of char ||~| is inconsistent
Set @myStr ='amol||~||'

Select Case When RIGHT(@myStr,5) = '||~||'
            Then LEFT(@myStr,len(@myStr) - 5)
            Else @myStr
        End
```

Comment: So answer is: `select LEFT(@myStr, len(@myStr) - 5)`. such a huge explanation before that!  
Anyways, it will help to any newbie of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that your values end with the Special String, try

```
substring ( [Customer Num], 1, length([Customer Num]) - length(' ||~|| ') )
```

It's better, however, to safeguard against accidental Deletions:

```
substring ( 
      [Customer Num]
    , 1
    , Case coalesce(substr( [Customer Num], length([Customer Num]) - length(' ||~|| '), '_' )
          When ' ||~|| ' then length([Customer Num]) - length(' ||~|| ') 
          Else                length([Customer Num])
      End
)
```

If your rdbms Supports regular expressions, this simplifies to (using Oracle Syntax)

```
Regexp_replace ( [Customer Num], ' \|\|~\|\| $', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to remove last 3 characters of ColumnX

```
set [ColumnX] = substring(ltrim(rtrim([ColumnX])),0,len([ColumnX]) - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
update [Table] set [Customer Num] = (substring(ltrim(rtrim([Customer Num])),0,len([Customer Num]) - 3))
where [Customer Num]  like '%only text containing this string%'
```